# AngularJS Filter expression not being updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

I have am dealing with two HTML files and one controller. In one HTML file I have a search bar:

```
  <a ui-sref="allSubmissions">
    <input id="searchBar" ng-controller="submissions" ng-model="searchString" class="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</a>
```

Along with some other stuff. In a separte HTML file, I have a list of submissions that I populate with ng-repeat:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="submissions">
    <ul class="subsList">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in submissionCollectionTest | filter: searchString" class="submissionDivider hover">
                <span class="ageText">{{item.age}}</span>
                <span class="submissionsText">{{item.submission}}</span>
                <span class="descriptionText">{{item.description}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Along with some other code. It makes sense in my complete app that these files be separate, however, I cannot get the search input to tie to the filter expression and automatically update. 
In my controller, i have the following scope variable:

```
myApp.controller('submissions',function($scope){


$scope.searchString = '';
```

When I click in the search bar, it takes me to the new page with shows all the content populated from the ng-repeat, then I want to filter the content by typing in the search bar. This does work when I have the search bar code in the same place as the content. How can I update "searchString" globally so that the filter responds when it changes? Thanks

Comment: `In my controller, i have the following scope variable`... which controller?

Comment: "submissions", the one in ng-controller in both HTML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a broadcast from one controller and listen in another.  If you're using multiple routes, then you'll want to store the search term in a service.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h0bd88dc/

```
function SearchSubmissionsCtrl($rootScope,Service) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.searchString = Service.searchString;
     vm.search = search;

     function search() {
        Service.searchString = vm.searchString;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('search', vm.searchString);
     }
  }

  function SubmissionsCtrl($scope,Service) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.searchString = Service.searchString;
     vm.items = [{
        age: 22,
        submission: 'Yes',
        description: 'Yo'
     }, {
        age: 5,
        submission: 'Derp',
        description: 'Hey'
     }];

     $scope.$on('search', function(e, string) {
        vm.searchString = string;
     })
  }

  function Service() {
    var service = {
        searchString: null
     };

     return service;
  }
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this out. What if i use the same controller?

Comment: Well, if you use the same controller then you wouldn't have to broadcast the search.  You would just have the searchString bound from the same controller.  But if you're using routes, you'll still want to store and fetch the searchString from a service.

Comment: I see. Right now im using just one controller and it is not working but I am using routes. So i guess i will store and fetch from a service